# How to create a search box with input in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i create a search box with an input in JavaScript or Jquery. Unfortunately i only know how to do it in html?. I have tried different things and have tried to search everywhere but the only ones i see are those in html combined with JavaScript. I wanna be able to do this in only JavaScript of Jquery.

Comment: Uh, everything comes down to the DOM or Canvas. There's no magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an input in JS you just have to use the createElement method like this :

```js
// Create your element
var input = document.createElement('input');

// Append your element tot the DOM
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

You can append elements in other elements as well : you don't have to use document.body everywhere. You can also create other elements like 'div', 'span' etc... using this method.

Have a look on [that](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to understand DOM management in javascript ;)